# How to get filecount per folder

Tags: c#

Lets say i have a a folder `Main` and inside `Main` i have another 2 folders
folder 1 is `Test` and in `Test` there are 2 files.
folder 2 is `Test2` and in `Test2` there are 3 files.

now i want an output like:

```
    Name: Test  Count: 2
    Name: Test2 Count: 3
```

I know that i can get all files with `Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Dir\", "*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`
But how can i achive this output?

Comment: `var filesCount = Directory.GetDirectories(@"[Your Path]").Select(d => new { Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d), Count = Directory.GetFiles(d).Length});`

Comment: @Jimi You want to use `GetFileName` instead for folders, since `.` dot is part of valid folder name characters

Comment: @Xiaoy312  Not an answer :) Just a snippet someone can build upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use loop through each sub-directory with `Directory.GetDirectories`:

```
foreach(var subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\Dir\"))
//foreach(var subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\Dir\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    // using GetFileName because subdirectory doesnt end with "\"
    var name = Path.GetFileName(subdirectory);
    var count = Directory.GetFiles(subdirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;

    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name} Count: {count}");
}
```

Use the commented line if you need to list the nested directories too.